# WinForms - Inheritance Picker - Unable to load (irrelevant) assembly, how do I avoid it?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm using VS2010, and developing a C# WinForms app.

I would like to create a new form, that inherits from a form in a different dll.  I right click on my project, hit 'add new item' and then under 'forms' click 'inherited from'.

At this point I get the error: 'Unable to load assembly 'X'. Ensure that the file is a valid .net framewrok assembly'.  I hit OK, and then get another error for 'Y' project.  They are both C# .net 4.0 winforms projects.

The important note here.  I don't care about those two projects.  I have 270 projects in my solution, and Neither of them are even control libraries.  They are .exes.

So, the question:

*Is there someway to mark the entire dll as "Im not going to be using any public types, and i don't want to ever load from the inheritance picker"?  If not, is there anything I can look for that would help figure out why these 2 of 270 projects wont load?*

I know I can just create a new form and manually type the actual class I want to derive from.  I need visual studio to work the intended way, and wanting to avoid shortcuts.  Also, i've gone through and marked every single class in both projects as either private or internal.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to inherit from anything in another DLL, you've got to reference that DLL in the project where the child class/interface is. Have you done the references yet?

Comment: Yeah, there references are there.  The inheritance picker is still making me search for the dll I want to inherit from, however.  I'm not sure why.  I think the errors mentioned above are aborting the automatic loading of referenced dll's.

Comment: Inheriting a form requires the assembly to be built and the form class you want to inherit from to be public.  Sounds like you've been doing the exact opposite.

Comment: How so?  My .exe wants to inherit from a form in a .dll, from the same solution.  I have the references setup correctly, and everything built.  The inheritance picker is throwing errors to completely unrelated projects.